# pop come at login to my app when i run it using e2e

Tags: angular, protractor, ionic2

In my app i when i try to check the login functionality chrome shows its in build alert box requesting for password

```
it('1 Should start out with empty username and password field',() => {
        expect(element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).getAttribute("value")).toEqual("");
        expect(element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(1).getAttribute("value")).toEqual("");
    });

    it('2 should fail with Wrong credentials', () => {

        element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).sendKeys("Spider Man");
        expect(element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).getAttribute("value")).toEqual("Spider Man");
        element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(1).sendKeys("Bat man");
        expect(element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(1).getAttribute("value")).toEqual("Bat man");
        element(by.id('logInButton')).click();
         element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).clear();
         element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(1).clear();
    })


    it('3 should login with Right credentials', () => {
        element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).sendKeys("neeraj");
        expect(element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).getAttribute("value")).toEqual("neeraj");
        element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(1).sendKeys("123456");
        element(by.id('logInButton')).click();
        browser.driver.navigate().refresh();  
    });
```

I don't want that additional popup to raise up
it looks something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your server to not require authentication or use a server for testing that doesn't.

Comment: is there any way to block this popup through protractor

Comment: I don't think there is a way to block it at all. Do you know where it's coming from?

Comment: if i give right username and password its not coming and if i give wrong password its comeing